# LinkedIn API login returning ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: linkedin-api

Attempting to authenticate with my LinkedIn application is failing. The request with ?code= appears to time out, and returns an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. Nothing has changed with my LinkedIn application configuration or with my integrations with the LinkedIn application. Unfortunately it does not look as though the LinkedIn API provides a status page.